# create several orders out of one order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

In my current magento shop project each product has a single validity_date as additional attribute, which will get set while product creation.

As a customer you can fill in your cart with different products and when you want to buy them, it should create not a single order with all products. It should create an order for each day.

I would like to know now what event is best to cancel the order and create instead of it several ones. Also how can I delete the old order? And is there a way to duplicate the order object and just change the products of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you are looking for is

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

Here you have:

```
public function checkoutSubmitAfter($observer)
{

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote = $event->getQuote();
    $quote_id = $quote->getId();
    $order = $event->getOrder();

    //add here your logic to create new orders from current order products..
}

$quote_items = $quote->getAllItems();
```

Starting here you can create a function to create custom orders for each product, and remove products from your initial order. No point in deleting the entire order, just consider that your first order..